# Flex 3.5 Validator Error Message Repeats

Tags: apache-flex

Anybody have any idea why the error message repeats in Flex SDK 3.5 (but not in 3.4) and have a good way to make it stop repeating? See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

You can also see the different apps here:

http://www.flexdevelopers.com/examples/validator/3.4/Tester.html

http://www.flexdevelopers.com/examples/validator/3.5/Tester.html

[View source is enabled on both apps]

To make this happen, leave the textInput field empty and hit save multiple times. Then mouseover the textInput.

I can think of a couple of solutions but they seem pretty hacky.

Thanks,

[Jeremy Mitchell](http://blog.flexdevelopers.com/)

Comment: Ok, it appears that an unresolved bug exists for this issue: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-22911

Comment: After looking at the source code of my apps, you may be wondering why I create a new validator every time I hit the save button. Well, I do this because of this bug :( - https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25731

Comment: You should look to migrate to Flex 4 as soon as possible, Jeremy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hack to fix this in 3.5.

View the source of this file: http://www.flexdevelopers.com/examples/validator/3.5/Tester.html

Change the saveMessage() method to read like this:

```
public function saveMessage(event:Event):void
        {
            setupValidators();

            var failedValidations:Array = new Array();
            failedValidations = Validator.validateAll(_formValidators);

            if (failedValidations.length == 0)
            {
                Alert.show("save it");
            }
            else
            {
                for each (var validationResultEvent:ValidationResultEvent in failedValidations)
                {
                    hackForSDK35Bug22911ToRemoveRepeatingErrorMessages(validationResultEvent);
                }
            }
        }
```

then add this method:

```
private function hackForSDK35Bug22911ToRemoveRepeatingErrorMessages(failedValidation:ValidationResultEvent):void
        {
            var uiComponent:UIComponent = failedValidation.target.source as UIComponent;
            var errorString:String = uiComponent.errorString as String;
            uiComponent.errorString = errorString.split("\n")[0];
        }
```

that should remove the repeating error messages and leave just one...